# problem when adding new item to start of array in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm facing a wired issue when adding a new item to the start of the array

checkout the example

```js
class Demo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {arr: [{title: 3}, {title: 2}, {title: 1}]};
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            {
                this.state.arr.map((item, index) => <Element title={item.title} isNew={item.isNew}
                                                             key={index}/>
                )}
            <button onClick={() => {
                const arr = [...this.state.arr];
                const newItem = this.state.arr.length + 1;
                arr.unshift({title: newItem, isNew: true});
                this.setState({arr: arr});
            }}>ADD ELEMENT TO START
            </button>
        </div>
    }
}

class Element extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log('constructor : ', this.props.title);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('componentDidMount : ', this.props.title);
    }

    render() {
        return <span style={{padding : '0 8px' , color: this.props.isNew ? 'red' : 'black'}}>{this.props.title}</span>
    }

}

ReactDOM.render(<Demo/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

checkout the **log** when adding a new item to the start of the array, it shows the props of the last item of the array, not the first (since we add the item to the start).

I'm changing the state as required, **the rendering is correct** but the constructor of the wrong component(the last component) gets called the same goes for `componentDidMount`.

the app will work perfectly when adding the item to the end of the array but not the opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a misuse of `key` in React.

Your `<Element key={index} ... />` code uses the index of the `state.arr` array to key your items and React uses that `key` to figure out if anything has changed.

When you add an item to the start, the new item gets assigned the key `0`, which already existed in the old item list, so React will notice no difference and not update the first 3 elements. On the fourth element, it will try to render the new element, but the 4th thing in the array is actually the last element of the original array.

Try indexing on the unique part of your object, e.g. the `title` or something, so React can correctly figure out when to update what.